# How to override layout.html.twig from FOSUserBundle

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I know that this question is perfectly answered in FOSUserBundle documentation, but yet I can't solve my problem.

I am trying to make an own login page using FOSUserBundle.

I have a `main.html.twig` that is EXACTLY the same as the `login.html.twig` included in the FOSUserBundle source.

The only difference is that main.html.twig is in my own bundle structure and login.html.twig is in FOSUserBundle folder structure.

I reach both `/login` and `/main`. I resolve them and the render starts.

But when accessing `/main`, I get the following error:

> Twig_Error_Runtime: Variable "csrf_token" does not exist in "AcmeStoreBundle:Main:main.html.twig" at line 5

The code is known by the FOSUserBundle users, but anyway I paste it here:

```
<form action="{{ path("fos_user_security_check") }}" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="_csrf_token" value="{{ csrf_token }}" />

<label for="username">{{ 'security.login.username'|trans({}, 'FOSUserBundle') }}</label>
<input type="text" id="username" name="_username" value="" />

<label for="password">{{ 'security.login.password'|trans({}, 'FOSUserBundle') }}</label>
<input type="password" id="password" name="_password" />

<input type="checkbox" id="remember_me" name="_remember_me" value="on" />
<label for="remember_me">{{ 'security.login.remember_me'|trans({}, 'FOSUserBundle') }}</label>

<input type="submit" id="_submit" name="_submit" value="{{ 'security.login.submit'|trans({}, 'FOSUserBundle') }}" />
```

The variable "csrf_token" is somehow not recognized from outside FOSUserBundle. Or something else that I am not getting.

Any clue over there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are not using `FormBuilder`, in your action that is responsible for rendering `main.html.twig` you should generate this token and pass it to the View.

```
$csrf = $this->get('form.csrf_provider'); //Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Csrf\CsrfProvider\SessionCsrfProvider by default
$token = $csrf->generateCsrfToken($intention); //Intention should be empty string, if you did not define it in parameters
```

You should pass `$token` as `csrf_token` variable to your View

Check also [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11632713/970721) to similar question

Comment: Yeah, that was it! Very silly of me, by the way :) Thanks a lot.