# Symfony CSRF and Ajax

Tags: ajax, symfony, csrf

I am trying to implement some ajax functionality in my Symfony 2 project. Using jquery's $.post I want to send some data back to my controller. However, when I just POST the data no CSRF protection is in place, as symfony's csrf protection only seems to apply to forms.

What would be a pretty straightforward way to implement this?

When using forms I can just do $form->isValid() to find out whether or not the CSRF token passes. I am currently placing everything I want to POST in a form and then posting that. Which basically means I am only using that form to implement CSRF protection, which seems hacky.

Comment: Aren't all of the other pages just accessible pages from the user any way? Meaning that the usual security.yml settings would stop people who should be see this seeing it.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In Symfony2 CSRF token is based on session by default. If you want to generate it, you just have to get this service and call generation method:

```
//Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Csrf\CsrfProvider\SessionCsrfProvider by default
$csrf = $this->get('form.csrf_provider');
//Intention should be empty string, if you did not define it in parameters
$token = $csrf->generateCsrfToken($intention); 

return new Response($token);
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11466837/970721) might be useful for you

Comment: Alright, that solves half of the problem. Now I would need to verify if the POST'ed token, I would do that with this: http://api.symfony.com/2.0/Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/Csrf/CsrfProvider/SessionCsrfProvider.html#method_isCsrfTokenValid

Comment: Now I would need to return the token into the template. As the post is made from a full-fledged HTML page, I could put it in a div with a CSS hidden property, and let every ajax-enabled script on that page use it. But as the token is only valid once, I would have to let every ajax POST return a new token and set that back into the hidden div. Now if a request is made, and the response times out, serverside a new token would've been generated but it wouldn't be set. Small chance this happens though.

I am going to accept this as an answer, although It still feels really hacky.

Comment: @peterrus Well... If you are not happy with this native behavior - you can write your own csrf_provider and implement behavior that you need :)

Comment: Well the problem is not in the csrf provider afaik. In fact there isn't really a problem now, but I would feel more certain about it if this workflow was described in the official documentation ;)

Comment: For embedding the token: Setting the X-CSRF-Token header seems like a neat solution:

http://erlend.oftedal.no/blog/?blogid=118

Comment: @peterrus Although this is an older question/answer I'm wondering if you have a working example since I have the same issue where I have many "formless" inputs that are sending data to my server with no CSRF protection at the moment. Thanks

Comment: Sorry John, I haven't been using symfony for a few years now :(

Comment: No problem @peterrus. Thanks for the reply either way as I've figured this one out :)

Comment: The name of the service is changed to `security.csrf.token_manager` in Symfony 3. The interface is changed, too. You need to call `getToken()` instead of `generateCsrfToken()`.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem, intermittently. Turned out it was not due to my ajax, but because Silex gives you a deprecated `DefaultCsrfProvider` which uses the session ID itself as part of the token, and I change the ID randomly for security. Instead, explicitly telling it to use the new `CsrfTokenManager` fixes it, since that one generates a token and stores it **in** the session, such that the session ID can change without affecting the validity of the token.

```
/** Use a CSRF provider that does not depend on the session ID being constant. We change the session ID randomly */
$app['form.csrf_provider'] = $app->share(function ($app) {
    $storage = new Symfony\Component\Security\Csrf\TokenStorage\SessionTokenStorage($app['session']);
    return new Symfony\Component\Security\Csrf\CsrfTokenManager(null, $storage);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try this snippet. Symfony form should generate special _csrf_token that should be send with post request. Without this value security alert will be raised.

Of course #targetForm should be replaced by form id and /endpoint by target ajax url

```
$('#targetForm').bind('submit', function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();
    var data = $(this).serialize();

    $.post('/endpoint', data, function(data) {
        // some logic here
    });

});
```

Comment: Yes, But I am trying not to use a form for every bit of ajax that I want to use. Still good option for sending forms over ajax!

Answer (score 0):

In Symfony 4+ you can use dependency injection right into your controller or action or wherever, for example, if you are submitting a form and wish to refresh the token of the same form, the `$tokenId` is the FQDN of the form type class:

```
namespace App\Controller;

use App\Form\MyFormType;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Csrf\CsrfTokenManagerInterface;

class MyController extends AbstractController
{
    public function submit(CsrfTokenManagerInterface $tokenManager): JsonResponse
    {
        // ...
        $token = $tokenManager->refreshToken(MyFormType::class);
        return new JsonResponse(['token' => $token->getValue()]);
    }
}
```

And in your JavaScript you can update the existing token `<input>`.

```
const token = document.getElementById('_token');
fetch(url, opts)
    .then(resp => resp.json())
    .then(response => {
        if (response.token) {
            token.value = response.token;
        }
    });
```