# Does Symfony 2 accept CSRF via header?

Tags: symfony, csrf

I wonder if SF2 accepts X-CSRF-Token via the header or if not is there an easy to make it do it. I'm changing some of my forms to be submitted with restful service instead and would love to pass X-CSRF-Token via the header.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can !

```
$csrf = $this->get('form.csrf_provider');//Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Csrf\CsrfProvider\SessionCsrfProvider by default
$token = $csrf->generateCsrfToken($intention); //Intention should be empty string, if you did not define it in parameters

return new Response($token);
```

Check this subject, it may help you :
[Symfony CSRF and Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12054449/symfony-csrf-and-ajax)

Comment: Hi Hornth, perhaps I misunderstand you, but my question is that assuming I already have csrf token, I want to pass it to Symfony2 via the header instead of the body. Why? The reason is that I can pass it via get request and other requests as well (not just post)

Comment: Not sure if it works (I haven't tried it), but check this :
http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/introduction.html#response