# Is there way to get a CSRF token from form object in Symfony2?

Tags: php, symfony

I try to get CSRF token from my form to send it through Ajax response. This is my code:

`$uploadForm = $this->createForm(new FilesUploadType(), new FilesUpload(), [
        'action' => $this->generateUrl('files_upload')
    ])->handleRequest($request);`

I have tried to get that so:

`$uploadForm->get('_token').getData();`

But that doesn't works.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12054449/symfony-csrf-and-ajax

Comment: Are token generated when Twig template is compiled?